# Is the comma needed in "additional, custom apps"?

Tags: modifiers

I saw the phrase "additional, custom apps." Is the comma correct? Or would you delete the comma:
"... additional custom apps ..."

The whole sentence is a bit complex, so I'll give a simplified version:

> Customers and partners can improve the functionality of their workspace with additional, custom apps within the platform.

Comment: I think you need to provide the whole sentence for this to be answerable.

Comment: The comma does make a small difference in meaning here.

Answer (score 2):

> with additional, custom apps within the platform.

I agree with the comment by @Spencer that it's a good idea to provide the original text. However I also agree with @Yosef Baskin that the comma makes a difference.

*... with additional, custom apps within the platform.*

This means that the apps are both additional **and** custom. You don't have any yet, but you can buy them if you think they will be useful.

*... with additional custom apps within the platform.*

This means that you already have some custom apps but that you can get more custom apps if you wish.